# ExtJS 4.0 pie chart resize legend based on pie chart to prevent overlapping

Tags: javascript, extjs

IS it possible to split the legend of an ExtJS 4.0 pie chart if the amount of space remaining would force a page scroll?  What we are currently experiencing is on a vertical re-size (user enabled) the legend retains the same size and thus becomes unreadable.  The question is can the legend be redrawn in such a way that it gains multiple columns to fit within its new dimensions?  We do not want to place the pie chart in an `iframe` and force that `iframe` to be scrollable.

[Example](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/charts/pie/viewer.html)